# export tuple from pandas to sql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2

I am working in jupyter notebook and I want to export a tuple to sql(in where condition). But id does not work.

```
numb = ('1','2', '3')


query =  """ SELECT *
              from table
              where table.number in numb """

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', user='user', 
                        password='pass', host='host' ,port ='port')
```

but this works

```
query =  """ SELECT *
              from table
              where table.number in ('1','2', '3') """

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', user='user', 
                        password='pass', host='host' ,port ='port')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed it by an inch, the below code should work:

```
numb = ('1','2', '3')


query =  f""" SELECT *
              from table
              where table.number in {numb} """

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', user='user', 
                        password='pass', host='host' ,port ='port')
```

or

```
numb = ('1','2', '3')


query =  """ SELECT *
              from table
              where table.number in {} """.format(numb)

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', user='user',
                        password='pass', host='host' ,port ='port')
```

output of `print(query)`:

```
 SELECT *
              from table
              where table.number in ('1', '2', '3')
```

Please note there are several other ways too. You need to look at python [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).